# Создание всплывающего окна для chrome extension

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, popup

Необходимо при двойном клике получить доступ к DOM вкладки и нарисовать в определённом месте всплывающее окно.

Насколько я понимаю, именно content_scripts имеет доступ к DOM вкладки и может её изменять.

Была осуществлена попытка добавить новый класс в DOM для дальнейшего взаимодействия с ним.

content.js:

```js
document.addEventListener("dblclick", function(event) {

      let popup = document.body.classList.add('popup');
      let arrow = document.body.classList.add('arrow');

      // Remove all child elements
      popup.innerHTML = '';

      popup.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
          `<div class="result">Some text</div>)
}
```

manifest.json:

```js
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.93",
  "description": "",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
      "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "css": ["myStyles.css"],
    "all_frames": true
  }],
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "background.js"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
}
```

Но в таком случае исходный DOM полностью замещается на добавленные мной классы popup и arrow.

Почему так происходит и как этого избежать? Каким образом создаётся всплывающее окно для chrome extension и в каком файле прописывается его поведение? **Любая** помощь будет полезна.

Comment: Вопрос ещё актуален ?

Comment: @grime Да, конечно

Comment: `let popup = document.body.classList.add('popup');` - Это не код создания html элемента. Это вы добавляете класс к `body`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// content.js

document.addEventListener("dblclick", function(event) {
 // координаты всплывающего окна относительно страницы
 const xCoord = event.pageX, yCoord = event.pageY;
 // шаблон всплывающего окна
 const myPopup = document.createElement('div');
 myPopup.classList.add('my-popup');
 // содержание всплывающего окна
 myPopup.innerHTML = '<p class="any-class">any content</p>';
 // позиция всплывающего окна в зависимости от места дабл-клика
 myPopup.style.cssText = `top: ${yCoord}px; left: ${xCoord}px;`;
 // если вам нужна переменная для body
 const body = document.body;
 body.append(myPopup)
})
```

```css
/* myStyles.css */

.my-popup {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: teal;
 position: absolute;
}
```